# Error when running meta-analysis of LCIA methods notebook

Tags: brightway

I am learning Brightway2 and I have been doing the [notebooks](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/tree/master/notebooks) from the brightway2 Github repo. So far all notebooks I have done have run smoothly, I am stuck in one concerning [Meta-analysis of LCA methods](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Meta-analysis%20of%20LCIA%20methods.ipynb), more specifically when running line [8].

This line computes 50.000 LCA calculations and times them. Here is the code:

```
from time import time
start = time()
lca_scores, methods, activities = get_lots_of_lca_scores()
print(time() - start)</code>
```

This enters into a never-ending loop, with the following message repeating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../miniconda3/envs/bw2_rosetta/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/.../miniconda3/envs/bw2_rosetta/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/.../miniconda3/envs/bw2_rosetta/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/Users/.../miniconda3/envs/bw2_rosetta/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'many_activities_one_method' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I tried looking at the called functions `def many_activities_one_method(activities, method)` and `def get_lots_of_lca_scores()`. But I had no luck and when I make changes I have the feeling I make things worse.

**Here is my question:** Has anyone tried this notebook and worked successfully? What could I be missing?

*Note: I have done the required notebook `Getting started with Brightwway2`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notebook has been updated to remove this error.